# How to hide a label within uitableview custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom UiTableView with a few cells.
Each cell contains a few UILabels.
somtimes I want to hide a specific label, while keeping its position empty, to avoid other fields repositioning.

in android, I used the following code:

```
holder.layoutTemperature.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); // hide, but keep its place. 
if (myFlag) {
  holder.layoutTemperature.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

How do I do it in swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can any View's visibility like this:

```
myLabel.isHidden = true
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.lbl.isHidden = true/false
```

Comment: I understand what you mean, but written verbatim, this will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the label but keep its position , you simply set its ".isHidden" to "true".
For example,

```
let label = UILabel()
label.isHidden = true
```